# Help to identify middle click microswitch in Razer Naga mouse

Tags: switches, identification

Can someone please identify microswitch used for mouse wheel click (sw3 on the pcb)? Here is an [Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3oeH.jpg) with Naga disassembly.

Recently my Razer Naga middle click became less responsive. It requires more force to respond. Since mouse's warranty has expired I decided to fix it myself. 
I looked up teardowns and fixes on the internet, but did not find exact model of microswitch used in the mouse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That switch may be a TACT switch as opposed to a microswitch. Some other mice use a small low profile tact switch disk taped over contacts on the circuit board.

Comment: Old post is super old but please don't use generic general purpose micro switches. They will work but you will need more force when pushing middle mouse. the razer micro switches (like the panasonic EVQP0E07K) are pushed 2 or 3 times easier than most common switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to address this is to remove the existing switch and carefully measure every dimension and lead spacing with a digital caliper. Then go to a distributor such as Mouser or Digikey and use their search tools to find various similar looking microswitches. Check the data sheets to see of the dimensions 
match up to yours.

[image]

A quick search on eBay for "mouse replacement micro switches" turned up some possible parts to look into. On eBay you may have to ask the seller for dimensions or data sheet. Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Old post is old but in case anyone is stumbling upon this they're Panasonic EVQP0E07K.

They can be found at DigiKey or Ebay for those like me who are not willing to pay 18 bucks for shipping a 50cts part :)

Comment: i've stumbled upon this! thanks!